# Highlight row in report?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a SSRS report which displays hundred of rows. I was wondering if there is anyway i can highlight the rows so that i can easily know on which row i am while accessing the report.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done in SSRS 2005. You cannot make any dynamic actions after report is generated.

Answer (score 1):

According to this thread on how to [highlight rows (background) with different color for mouse over property](https://web.archive.org/web/20110109051529/http://www.sqldev.org/sql-server-reporting-services/ssrs-highlight-rows-background-with-different-color-for-mouse-over-property-39689.shtml), it seems like this is not a feature that is supported by the software. Which means that you would need to create or find a custom report item to fit your needs.

*However*, another approach would be to [alternate background colors in Reporting Services](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/20/60691.aspx):

1. Go to the row Fill Property and choose Expression
   [image: Textbox Properties]
2. Add in something like `=IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2, "Silver", "White")`
   [image: Fill Expression]

Comment: Very similar to Crystal Reports =)